# How to pass a Silverlight application to someone?

Tags: .net, silverlight, deployment

I have a Silverlight application (just a XAP file). What is the easiest way to launch this application on the other machine? It uses WCF RIA services (locally). I just want to be able to show the result of my work to boss without installing Visual Studio on his computer.

Comment: I know how to deploy a Silverlight application without IIS. But it requires a stub for RIA Services, you will need to write the same methods which return dummy data. After that you can send only two files: xap and htm, and they will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also install XAP files as Out of Browser apps using the command line or Group Policy with Silverlight using SSLauncher.exe.  This is the same app that runs your OOB app normally.  You can specify /install (path to XAP).  See this for details: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/03/25/using-sllauncher-for-silent-install-silverlight-application.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I will try that approach. What about local WCF RIA services. Are they going to work properly?

Comment: If you are hosting RIA Services they are not truly local as they need to be installed on a web server.  The client portion is simply there to connect to the server project (*.web).  You'll need to deploy that appropriately to IIS somewhere first and point the client to pull from it.

Answer (score 3):

If your boss is on the same network as you then put your service and SL app in IIS and browse to your internal IP address from your boss' machine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a page to display the XAP file (you can perhaps copy the html output of the testpage and change the path to the XAP file)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are on same network with your boss then,

- Configure your IIS and host the WCF(Website) there (Say you hosted as 'MyTestService' in your localhost
- Have your .aspx or .html file with the Silverlight (say default.html)
- Share the link with your IP address to the boss which will be like 'http://[IPofyourMachine]/MyTestService/Default.html

If you are not in the same network, you may need to host it in a public domain and send the link.

Answer (score 0):

One option if you don't want to use IIS, is to use [CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/) as this will allow you to get RIA services up and running.

I know this for a fact, because I use it to run some integration tests automatically on a build server (using the dll).

The good thing about CassiniDev is that you don't have to install it - you can run the executable from an unzipped folder and then point it to your web site folder. It ends up running pretty much identical to the inbuilt web server that Visual Studio uses (Cassini).